# Get existing Google Maps V3 instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a WordPress plugin for a [Store Locator](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-store-locator/), and it does a lot of good things. But there are a few things that I need to tweak and I do not want to modify the plugin's code. I was wondering if there was any way to get ahold of the current map that it outputs and all of its settings so that I could manipulate them, or add to them? I would do this in my own JS file.

The ID of the div that contains the map is `#wpsl-gmap` and one thing I want to do is after loading the results I need to trigger a resize on the map because the area that it is loaded into increases and the tiles do not load for the new section. I would also like to center the map if possible.

Comment: Please add your current relevant code. It makes answering a lot simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253265/get-google-maps-map-instance-from-a-htmlelement 

For your specific issue are you able to view the  JS code of the plugin you are trying to modify if the variable used to store the map when it is created is in the global namespace you may be able to access it from your JS

Comment: It does not appear that the developer of the plugin has left the map object in a global namespace. I am not sure if I am allowed to upload his full JS file, but I can link you to the plugin and tell you where the file is that controls the map functionality it. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-store-locator/ is the link, and the map functions are in `js/wpsl-gmap.js`, however the plugin uses the minified version. Here is the page I am working on http://yuasabatteries.com.synapseresults.com/find-a-dealer/ and the file that I want to work in is in theme `store-locator.js`. I hope this helps!

Comment: you can use US Postal Code `17601` to get results